# Derive a 4-week period column from week column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a aggregated weekly data in my SQL table. The date column is the Monday of every week, like below:

```
date
2019-11-25
2019-11-18
2019-11-11
2019-11-04
2019-10-28
2019-10-21
2019-10-14
2019-10-07
2019-09-30
..........
```

What I need is two derived columns `periodId` like `1,2,3,...` and also `period` with defined daterange like `2019-11-04:2019-11-25`.

```
date      periodId  period
2019-11-25    1    2019-11-04:2019-11-25
2019-11-18    1    2019-11-04:2019-11-25
2019-11-11    1    2019-11-04:2019-11-25
2019-11-04    1    2019-11-04:2019-11-25
2019-10-28    2    2019-10-07:2019-10-28
2019-10-21    2    2019-10-07:2019-10-28
2019-10-14    2    2019-10-07:2019-10-28
2019-10-07    2    2019-10-07:2019-10-28
2019-09-30    3    ................
..........
```

How to do that in SQL or is it possible for such manipulation in SQL? I'm in SQL Server.

Comment: Is the `date` column of date datatype or it's a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` to generate groups of 4 consecutive records, starting with the latest one. Then, you can do window `min()`s and `max()`s over the groups:

```
select
    date,
    periodId,
    concat(
        cast(min(date) over(partition by periodId) as varchar),
        ':',
        cast(max(date) over(partition by periodId) as varchar)
    ) period
from (
    select date, (row_number() over(order by date desc) + 3) / 4 periodId       
    from mytable 
) t
```

This assumes that `date` is of `date` datatype. If it's a string in `yyymmdd` format, no need to `cast()`.

```
select
    date,
    periodId,
    concat(
        min(date) over(partition by periodId),
        ':',
        max(date) over(partition by periodId)
    ) period    
from (
    select date, (row_number() over(order by date desc) + 3) / 4 periodId       
    from mytable 
) t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1a8f3b4a34d7fb87be0fe849cf71d434)**:

```
date       | periodId | period               
:--------- | :------- | :--------------------
2019-11-25 | 1        | 2019-11-04:2019-11-25
2019-11-18 | 1        | 2019-11-04:2019-11-25
2019-11-11 | 1        | 2019-11-04:2019-11-25
2019-11-04 | 1        | 2019-11-04:2019-11-25
2019-10-28 | 2        | 2019-10-07:2019-10-28
2019-10-21 | 2        | 2019-10-07:2019-10-28
2019-10-14 | 2        | 2019-10-07:2019-10-28
2019-10-07 | 2        | 2019-10-07:2019-10-28
2019-09-30 | 3        | 2019-09-30:2019-09-30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a subquery if you like:

```
select date,
       row_number() over (order by date) + 3 as period,
       concat(convert(varchar(10), 
                      dateadd(week, row_number() over (order by date) - 1, date)
                     ),
              ':',
              convert(varchar(10), 
                      dateadd(week, row_number() over (order by date) + 3, date)
                     )
             ) as dates
from t;
```